# Excel XLookUp table array - using column numbers instead of Addresses

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the first populated cell to the right of the current cell, and return the header value.
And if I hard code, I've got that:

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,TBL_Plan[[#Headers],[2023-12-04]:[2024-01-15]]<>"",TBL_Plan[@[2023-12-04]:[2024-01-15]],,,1)
```

However, I can't leave it with hard-coded addresses as people will change the values used for column headers.

I know the current column is `Column()`, and the last column is `columns(TBL_Plan)` - so I would like to define my table array something like this :

```
 TBL_Plan[[#Headers],Column()+1:columns(TBL_Plan)]
 TBL_Plan[@column():columns(TBL_Plan)]
```

But .. I can't quite find a workable way of declaring the table arrays by indexes instead of addresses.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Note that column headers of tables are always text, so if you're looking for a date, convert the range you want to lookup into text, or change the header strings into values.

Comment: Thanks @P.b, noted. Now using datevalue of returned literals to cast to dates 

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in a new sheet:

| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4 | Header 5 | Header 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(OFFSET(A2,0,1,1,COLUMNS(2:2)-COLUMNS($A2:A2)))/(OFFSET(A2,0,1,1,COLUMNS(2:2)-COLUMNS($A2:A2))<>""),1)) | a |  |  |  |  |
| =INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(OFFSET(A3,0,1,1,COLUMNS(3:3)-COLUMNS($A3:A3)))/(OFFSET(A3,0,1,1,COLUMNS(3:3)-COLUMNS($A3:A3))<>""),1)) |  | a |  |  |  |
| =INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(OFFSET(A4,0,1,1,COLUMNS(4:4)-COLUMNS($A4:A4)))/(OFFSET(A4,0,1,1,COLUMNS(4:4)-COLUMNS($A4:A4))<>""),1)) |  |  | a |  |  |
| =INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(OFFSET(A5,0,1,1,COLUMNS(5:5)-COLUMNS($A5:A5)))/(OFFSET(A5,0,1,1,COLUMNS(5:5)-COLUMNS($A5:A5))<>""),1)) |  |  |  | a |  |
| =INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(OFFSET(A6,0,1,1,COLUMNS(6:6)-COLUMNS($A6:A6)))/(OFFSET(A6,0,1,1,COLUMNS(6:6)-COLUMNS($A6:A6))<>""),1)) |  |  |  |  | a |

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
=LET(row,INDEX(Table1[#Data],ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers]),0),
startCol,COLUMN()-INDEX(COLUMN(Table1[#Headers]),1)+2,
endCol,COLUMNS(Table1[#Headers]),
findCol,XMATCH(TRUE,INDEX(row,startCol):INDEX(row,endCol)<>""),
INDEX(Table1[#Headers],findCol+startCol-1))
```

I am guessing we might be in (say) Column2 of a table and want to find the header corresponding to the next non-blank cell to the right in each row so this would be one way where:

- row is the entire table row we are currently on
- startCol is the number of the table column after the one we are currently on
- endCol is the number of the last column in the table
- findCol is the position of the first non-blank cell to the right relative to the current column
- result is header index after adding start column and    subtracting
  one

[image]